# Read data from Azure Synpase to Azure Machine Learning by ManagedIdentityCredential

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to read data from Azure Synpase to Azure Machine Learning by ManagedIdentityCredential, But when I run the code, the kernel of notebook was restarted and can not run!

Do you know the method to read  data from Azure Synpase to Azure Machine Learning by ManagedIdentityCredential?

My code are as follows:

```
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
client_id = os.environ.get('DEFAULT_IDENTITY_CLIENT_ID')
credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id=client_id)
token = credential.get_token('https://storage.azure.com/')


# Define your Synapse connection details
synapse_server = "your-synapse-server-name.database.windows.net"
synapse_database = "database"

# Create a connection string using Managed Identity credentials
connection_string =  "Driver={...};Server=tcp:synapse_server,1433;Initial Catalog=synapse_database ;Connection Timeout=30;"

conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, attrs_before={1256:token})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver16#active-directory-managed-identity-authentication), you need the ODBC driver `17.3.1.1`.

Run the commands below to install ODBC driver version 18 on the Azure Machine Learning Studio.

```
%%sh

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18

sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18

echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc

sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
```

Install based on the OS and version.
For more information on installing, refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=alpine18-install%2Calpine17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline).

Next, check if the driver is available using `pyodbc`.

`pyodbc.drivers()`

[image]

Based on that, provide the driver version in the connection string.

Code:

```py
import struct
import os
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

client_id = os.environ.get('DEFAULT_IDENTITY_CLIENT_ID')
credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(object_id=client_id)

token_bytes = credential.get_token('https://database.windows.net/').token.encode('utf-16-le')
token_struct = struct.pack(f'<I{len(token_bytes)}s', len(token_bytes), token_bytes)


connection_string =  'Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:jsynxxxx.sql.azuresynapse.net,1433;Database=master;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30'

conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string,attrs_before={1256:token_struct})


df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM sys.tables", conn) 
df.head()
```

Output:

[image]

**Note**: Make sure to configure managed identity in you ml workspace compute instance.